# wide to long with multiple header rows and merged cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have an excel sheet where the format is like this:

```
        Ardmore Woodford    Arkoma Woodford         
Date    Oil Gas Mis Total   Oil Gas Misc Total
2/4/2011    1   2   0   3   0   19  0    19
2/11/2011   1   3   0   4   0   19  0    19
2/18/2011   1   3   0   4   0   19  0    19
2/25/2011   1   3   0   4   0   19  0    19
3/4/2011    3   5   0   8   0   17  0    17
3/11/2011   2   4   0   6   0   19  0    19
3/18/2011   1   4   0   5   0   19  0    19
```

I would like to bring the dates across as column headers, and instead have the location as its own column value with another column for the product, such that the result looks like this:

```
Location            Product   2/11/2011   2/18/2011   2/25/2011   3/4/2011  
Ardmore Woodford    Oil       1           ...         ...         ...
Ardmore Woodford    Gas       3           ...         ...         ...
Ardmore Woodford    Misc      0           ...         ...         ...
Ardmore Woodford    Total     4           ...         ...         ...
Arkoma  Woodford    Oil       0           ...         ...         ...
Arkoma  Woodford    Gas       19          ...         ...         ...
Arkoma  Woodford    Misc      0           ...         ...         ...
Arkoma  Woodford    Total     19          ...         ...         ...
```

However I am struggling how to read it in since there are technically 2 column header rows and cells are merged in one. If I read them in using `header=[0,1]` then it appears to be read in correctly but the column names become tuples and I can't set an index, with the date columns becoming `('Unnamed: 0_level_0', 'Date')`. Beyond that, I don't know how to achieve this format. Thank you.

Comment: df=df.T ? is this ?

Comment: I never even knew this existed and I thought I had read a decent a mount before, thank you. How do I fill down the column for the multiindex for the merged cells? Is there an in line method or do I just do it afterwards

Comment: df.T.reset_index()

Comment: I'm officially mindblown, thank you. I'll keep track of this. Should I just delete the question or would you prefer to post as an answer?

Comment: You can keep it here ~ I post a community wiki answer ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `T` + `reset_index`

```
df = df.T.reset_index()
```